# Why doesnt my label show up in the window?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the script
#Imports
import os
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

```
#ws
ws = Tk()
ws.title('JCHS Chat')
ws.geometry('600x1000')

ws.mainloop()

root = Tk()
#Label Widget
myLabel = Label(root, text="You smell like dust")

#Actually putting it in
myLabel.pack()

#Looping the script
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: The text label wont show up in the window.

Comment: That is because your creating a new window called root

Comment: I updated the code and the issue is still not resolved

Comment: Does my answer help or were you looking for something different?

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and other [help] articles.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is your creating two windows instead of just one. you can fix this by change your code to this.

```
from tkinter import *

#ws
ws = Tk()
ws.title('JCHS Chat')
ws.geometry('600x1000')

#Label Widget
myLabel = Label(ws, text="You smell like dust")
#Actually putting it in
myLabel.pack()
ws.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using root instead of ws, here is a fix.

```
myLabel = Label(ws, text = "You smell like dust").pack()
```